# Why does measurable function need to be defined on a measurable domain?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

In Royden's book, he defines a function $f$ defined on $E$ to be measurable if $E$ is measurable and at least one (and therefore all) of the following sets are measurable:

$\{x \in E : f(x) > c\}$

$\{x \in E : f(x) \geq c\}$

$\{x \in E : f(x) > c\}$

$\{x \in E : f(x) \leq c\}$

where $c$ is any real number. My question is, are the 4 above sets measurable even if the domain $E$ is not measurable? Why do we need $E$ to be measurable?

Comment: It may be redundant because it follows when c is negative infinity

Comment: The union of measurable sets must be measurable. $E=[f>c] \cup [f \le c]$.

Comment: Would it have been possible for either [>] or [≤] to be measurable if $E$ were not measurable?